# Boost library for RTTI

Tags: c++, boost, rtti

which boost library should I use to implement RTTI in my project?? Is it Statechart library?

Comment: Statechart uses RTTI, not the other way around. RTTI is built in, and Boost does nothing to extend it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RTTI is built into the C++ language. However, you'll find a few RTTI-related, convenient tools in Boost, e.g. [Boost.TypeTraits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html) which enables you to checks such as `is_base_of()`, `has_trivial_constructor()` and loads of other stuff. [Boost.FunctionTypes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/function_types/doc/html/index.html) might also be worth checking out.

Answer (score 7):

RTTI is built into the C++ language, with features like [dynamic_cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cby9kycs.aspx) and [typeid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyf39xec.aspx). You don't need boost to use it.

Answer (score 2):

A simple RTTI is built into the C++ language, although you can opt out of it (decreases binary size). You can read about [RTTI in C++ here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/tic/tic0268.shtml).

If you're searching for something more robust (e.g. Reflection) unfortunately there's no simple solution for that, but it's planned for after-C++0x. There was a Reflection library suggested for Boost, but it hasn't been accepted (yet?). You can find it here : http://boost-extension.blogspot.com/